# Ionic 2 ngSwitch + <ion-select> = EXCEPTION: Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to build a connect/register page using Ionic 2. Of course, I have a `login.html` and a `login.ts` file.

I face an issue when I try to put a `<ion-select>` inside a `<div>` switching between two `<ion-list>`. The error is `EXCEPTION: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'`

There is something I dont understand and can't fix. I know there a lot of Q&A on this matter here. I think I tried them all but none helped me.

I understand that Angular checks for changes twice per round, and that this error is triggered when these do not return equal results. I just don't see why this code should have this problem, or how I can fix it. I don't want to disable dev mode, so if you have any idea on how to rework the code to avoid this, your suggestion would be welcome. TIA.

**login.ts**

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/login/login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {
    public loginSwitch:string = 'login'; // Default ion-list to show at startup
    public userCredentials = {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        type: 'individual'
    }

    constructor() {
    }

    login(formData) {
        console.log(formData);
    }

    register(formData) {
        console.log(formData);
    }
}
```

**login.html - Working but not useful**

```html
<ion-content padding class="login">
    <!-- *** I'm outside ngSwitch and working ** -->
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Are you?</ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="userCredentials.type">
            <ion-option value="individual">An individual</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="company">A company</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <!-- **************************************** -->
    <div center>
        <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="loginSwitch">
            <ion-segment-button value="login">
                Login
            </ion-segment-button>
            <ion-segment-button value="register">
                Register
            </ion-segment-button>
        </ion-segment>
    </div>
    <div [ngSwitch]="loginSwitch">
        <ion-list *ngSwitchWhen="'login'">
            <p style="text-align:center;">YOUR LOGIN CREDENTIALS</p>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-input type="email" placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="userCredentials.email"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="userCredentials.password"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
            <button block (click)="login(userCredentials)">Log me in</button>
        </ion-list>
        <ion-list *ngSwitchWhen="'register'">
            <p style="text-align:center;">CREATE YOUR PROFILE</p>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="name"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-input type="email" placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="userCredentials.email"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
            <button block (click)="register(userCredentials)">Register</button>
        </ion-list>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

**login.html - Useful but not working**

```html
<ion-content padding class="login">
    <div center>
        <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="loginSwitch">
            <ion-segment-button value="login">
                Login
            </ion-segment-button>
            <ion-segment-button value="register">
                Register
            </ion-segment-button>
        </ion-segment>
    </div>
    <div [ngSwitch]="loginSwitch">
        <ion-list *ngSwitchWhen="'login'">
            <p style="text-align:center;">YOUR LOGIN CREDENTIALS</p>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-input type="email" placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="userCredentials.email"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="userCredentials.password"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
            <button block (click)="login(userCredentials)">Log me in</button>
        </ion-list>
        <ion-list *ngSwitchWhen="'register'">
            <p style="text-align:center;">CREATE YOUR PROFILE</p>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="name"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-input type="email" placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="userCredentials.email"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <!-- *** I'm inside ngSwitch and NOT working ** -->
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>Are you?</ion-label>
                    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="userCredentials.type">
                        <ion-option value="individual">An individual</ion-option>
                        <ion-option value="company">A company</ion-option>
                    </ion-select>
                </ion-item>
                <!-- **************************************** -->
            </ion-list>
            <button block (click)="register(userCredentials)">Register</button>
        </ion-list>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't name your exact problem, but you could try another approach.
Maybe its something with adding/removing to/from the DOM..

Try to remove your switch/case and use the `[hidden]` attribute instead:

component:

```
private login: boolean = true; /* true = show login, false = show register */
```

template:

```
<ion-list [hidden]="!login"><!-- login -->

// ...

<ion-list [hidden]="login"><!-- register -->
```

Comment: Good idea! It works! +1. However it's a workaround. I hope we will find a solution according to Angular coding standards.

Comment: As I didn't found a "cleaner" solution, I accept this workaround as an answer. Txs.